# What is the physical significance of the negative sign in the lorentz force equation in presence of magnetic monopole?

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, magnetic-monopoles

This question is similar to that of: [Why does the extended Lorentz force law have a negative sign?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/669297/why-does-the-extended-lorentz-force-law-have-a-negative-sign)

The Lorentz force on a magnetic monopole is given as:
$$\vec{F}=q_m(\vec{B}-\vec{v}\times\frac{\vec{E}}{c^2})$$

I want to know what is the physical significance of the negative sign on the second term $(-\vec{v}\times\frac{\vec{E}}{c^2})$ in the above equation.

Any help regarding this will be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: its because of the change of sign on the  $J_m$ in the curl of E equation. If you imagine moving a magnetic charge conducting loop in  a E field, The analogue of the lorentz force produces an electric field that opposes the change in flux, this is only possible with the negative in the lorentz force, Its about energy conservation. As for why J is negative in the curl equation in the first place, probably has something to do with  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/597847/  The answer by : user281342

Comment: Without the minus sign, the force wouldn’t transform correctly under Lorentz transformations.